# use topLayoutGuide programmatically in swift2.1

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am using Swift2.1 and I want to add a subview to my view of the view controller, which has a navigationBar on top of the screen. So I tried to set constraints that subview.top equals self.topLayoutGuide.Bottom, my code is as the following:

[image]

As I run the app, it crashed with error:

[image]

Am I wrong editing the string of "V: [selfTopLayoutGuide]-[subview]-[selfBottomLayoutGuide]"?  Or is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pointing to the space in your string, remove it.

```
"V:[selfTopLayoutGuide]-[subview]-[selfBottomLayoutGuide]"
```

Comment: thanks, it doesn't come up the error. However, the subview would not show somehow, maybe I got wrong with the constraints.

Comment: Are you also adding a horizontal constraint to set the width?

Comment: yes, and how should set the vertical constraints so that subview.top equals  self.topLayoutGuide.Bottom

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not showing without looking at the rest if your code. But to stop seeing the gap between the topLayoutGuide and the subview, remove the "-" between them as this signifies a default margin.